# Strange result from arc4random_uniform(). Whats happened

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

yesterday i had the follow code:

```
NSInteger test = arc4random_uniform(10)-5;
```

if i checked via debugger whats inside test, sometimes it was not a number between -5 and 5. 
Sometime it was a random big integer.

After i changed the code to this:

```
NSInteger test = arc4random_uniform(10);
test -= 5;
```

i was only get a number between -5 and 5.
I'm pretty new to Objectiv C and normaly i only write C / C++. But this makes no sense for me.

Can someone explain what happend?

Comment: From what I guess, I didn't check the doc, but `arc4random_uniform` returns an unsigned integer, so that's why you might have got big numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arc4Random family of functions return `u_int32_t`.  The "u_" means unsigned, and determines the type of the expression with the literal `5`. So that first expression will (about half the time, for randoms < 5) produce an unsigned negative, which will be treated as nearly `UINT_MAX`.

The second expression casts the random as a signed int first, so the subsequent subtraction works as expected.